# Excel macro - Selecting cell range with a using number from loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to define a cell range (i.e. A1:F1) using the number from my iCounter as the row number.

Presently, my code is formatted like

```
Range(A & (iCounter - 2):F1 & (iCounter - 1)).Select
```

I am getting the Syntax Error statement.  I have researched and reformatted with quotation marks but I am still unable to get the format correct.

I have based this on a recording that used the hard coded:

```
Range("A1:F1").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark2
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

The code block I have adapted is below.  Thank you!

```
Step 5:  Start reverse looping through the range.
    For iCounter = MyRange.Rows.Count To 2 Step -3
    
'Step 6: Copy and Paste columns
        '
        Range("A" & (iCounter - 1)).Cut Range("A" & (iCounter - 2))
        'Add a color fill
        Range(A & (iCounter - 2):F1 & (iCounter - 1)).Select
        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark2
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With

        
'Step 7: Increment the counter down
    Next iCounter
```

Comment: `Range("A" & iCounter - 2 & ":F" & iCounter - 1).Select`.

Comment: Also see [How to avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: You could avoid `Select` by using `with Range("A" & iCounter - 2 & ":F" & iCounter - 1)`

Comment: Thank you so much.  I think I was missing the " before the colon `":F"`

Comment: I assume `Select` can introduce some errors?  I will read the link.  Thank you @BigBen and @cybernetic.nomad.